# Why is an extra element being added to my void** array when I use merge-sort?

Tags: c, mergesort, void-pointers

When I use `mergeSort` to sort my `void**` array (this array contains `void*` pointers that point to integers), an extra `1` (a new element) appears to be added to the array. I am nearly certain the issue is in `mergeSort` or `merge`, as when print my `void**` array before calling `mergeSort`, the data is correct (just unsorted). Here is the code.

```
#define SIZE 10

void mergeSort(void**, int, int);
void merge(void**, int, int, int);
int compare(void*, void*);

int main(void) {
    int array[SIZE] = { 5, 6, 3, 2, 5, 6, 7, 4, 9, 3 };
    void *voidArray[SIZE];
    int query = 1;
    void *queryPointer = &query;

    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
        voidArray[j] = &array[j];
    }

    printArray(voidArray);
    mergeSort(voidArray, 0, SIZE);
    printArray(voidArray);
    result = binarySearch(voidArray, 0, SIZE, queryPointer);

    if (result == -1) {
        puts("Query not found.");
        return(0);
    }

    printf("Query found at index %d.\n", result);
    return(0);
}

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

void mergeSort(void **array, int head, int tail) {
    if (head < tail) {
        int middle = (head + ((tail - head) / 2));
        mergeSort(array, head, middle);
        mergeSort(array, (middle + 1), tail);
        merge(array, head, middle, tail);
    }
}

void merge(void **array, int head, int middle, int tail) {
    int headLength = (middle - head + 1);
    int tailLength =  (tail - middle);
    void *headSide[headLength];
    void *tailSide[tailLength];

    for (int i = 0; i < headLength; i++) {
        headSide[i] = array[head + i];
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < tailLength; j++) {
        tailSide[j] = array[middle + 1 + j];
    }

    int k = head;
    int l = 0;
    int m = 0;
    while (l < headLength && m < tailLength) {
        if (compare(headSide[l], tailSide[m]) == -1) {
            array[k] = headSide[l];
            l++;      
        } else {  
            array[k] = tailSide[m];
            m++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    while (l < headLength) {
        array[k] = headSide[l];
        l++;
        k++;
    }

    while (m < tailLength) {
        array[k] = tailSide[m];
        m++;
        k++;
    }
}

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

int compare(void *index, void *query) {
    if (*((int *)index) == *((int *)query)) {
        return (0);
    }

    if (*((int*)index) > *((int*)query)) {
        return (1);        
    }

    return (-1);
}
```

The output should have the unsorted array, the sorted array, and whether the query was found. There is no `1` in the unsorted array, but then there is a `1` in the sorted array; also, the number `9` is missing from the sorted results (interestingly, if I perform a binary search for `9`, it will tell me that `9` is found at index `10`).

Example output (for a query of `1`):

```
5 6 3 2 5 6 7 4 9 3
1 2 3 3 4 5 5 6 6 7
```

Query found at index `0`.

Comment: You need to decide whether you work with closed or half-open intervals. At the moment you are mixing them.

Comment: As it sits, you would need to pass `mergeSort (voidArray, 0 , SIZE-1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your array subscript.

```
int tailLength =  (tail - middle)
```

**tail** is the size of array,I think **tailLength** is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, the tail of an array with 10 elements is 9, not 10 as I had assumed. Thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

```
headSide[i] = array[head + i];
```

`headSide[i]` is `void` and `array[head + i]` is `void*`

Answer (score 0):

There is some confusion in the arguments to `margeSort` and `merge`. Passing the index of the last element in the range is not idiomatic in C. It is much simpler to pass the index of the element after the end of the range, which is consistent with passing `0` and `SIZE` int `main()`: `mergeSort(voidArray, 0, SIZE);` and `result = binarySearch(voidArray, 0, SIZE, queryPointer);`

Here is a modified version with this API:

```c
void mergeSort(void **array, int head, int tail) {
    if (tail - head > 1) {
        int middle = head + (tail - head) / 2);
        mergeSort(array, head, middle);
        mergeSort(array, middle, tail);
        merge(array, head, middle, tail);
    }
}

void merge(void **array, int head, int middle, int tail) {
    int headLength = middle - head;
    int tailLength = tail - middle;
    void *headSide[headLength];
    void *tailSide[tailLength];

    for (int i = 0; i < headLength; i++) {
        headSide[i] = array[head + i];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < tailLength; j++) {
        tailSide[j] = array[middle + j];
    }

    int k = head;
    int l = 0;
    int m = 0;
    while (l < headLength && m < tailLength) {
        if (compare(headSide[l], tailSide[m]) <= 0) {
            array[k++] = headSide[l++];
        } else {  
            array[k++] = tailSide[m++];
        }
    }
    while (l < headLength) {
        array[k++] = headSide[l++];
    }
    while (m < tailLength) {
        array[k++] = tailSide[m++];
    }
}
```

Note however that allocating the temporary arrays `headSide` and `tailSide` with automatic storage (aka *on the stack*) is risky for large arrays.  Furthermore, it is not necessary to save the elements from the right half into `tailSide` as they will not be overwritten before they are copied to the final position. Here is a simpler version of `merge`:

```c
void merge(void **array, int head, int middle, int tail) {
    int headLength = middle - head;
    void *headSide[headLength];

    for (int i = 0; i < headLength; i++) {
        headSide[i] = array[head + i];
    }

    int k = head;
    int l = 0;
    while (l < headLength && middle < tail) {
        if (compare(headSide[l], array[middle]) <= 0) {
            array[k++] = headSide[l++];
        } else {  
            array[k++] = array[middle++];
        }
    }
    while (l < headLength) {
        array[k++] = headSide[l++];
    }
}
```